# How exactly does this delegating recursion example from YDKJS work?

Tags: javascript, promise, generator

I started reading You Don't Know JS: Async and Performance and tripped at [delegating recursion example](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch4.md#delegating-recursion): I went through the code mentally and got the right result, but can't comprehend the description of the intermediate steps in the book.

Tried inserting `console.log()` into the functions' body, tried debugger to examine the call stack and still cannot conform my mental model of the code to the one, that's in the book.

`function run()`, which gets generator function as parameter, creates its instance and run it to the end, passing each previously `yield`ed value to the `next()` call.

```
function run(gen) {
    var args = [].slice.call( arguments, 1), it;

    // initialize the generator in the current context
    it = gen.apply( this, args );

    // return a promise for the generator completing
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then( function handleNext(value){
            // run to the next yielded value
            var next = it.next( value );

            return (function handleResult(next){
                // generator has completed running?
                if (next.done) {
                    return next.value;
                }
                // otherwise keep going
                else {
                    return Promise.resolve( next.value )
                        .then(
                            // resume the async loop on
                            // success, sending the resolved
                            // value back into the generator
                            handleNext,

                            // if `value` is a rejected
                            // promise, propagate error back
                            // into the generator for its own
                            // error handling
                            function handleErr(err) {
                                return Promise.resolve(
                                    it.throw( err )
                                )
                                .then( handleResult );
                            }
                        );
                }
            })(next);
        } );
}
```

the example code:

```
function *foo(val) {
    if (val > 1) {
        // generator recursion
        val = yield *foo( val - 1 );
    }

    return yield request( "http://some.url/?v=" + val );
}

function *bar() {
    var r1 = yield *foo( 3 );
    console.log( r1 );
}

run( bar );
```

and for convenience's sake we can implement `function request()` like this:

```
function request(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve( url.match(/v=(\d+)$/)[1] );
        },1000);
    });
}
```

The book provides these steps:

1. `run(bar)` starts up the `*bar()` generator.
2. `foo(3)` creates an iterator for `*foo(..)` and passes `3` as its `val` parameter.
3. Because `3 > 1`, `foo(2)` creates another iterator and passes in `2` as its `val` parameter.
4. Because `2 > 1`, `foo(1)` creates yet another iterator and passes in `1` as its `val` parameter.
5. `1 > 1` is `false`, so we next call `request(..)` with the `1` value, and get a promise back for that first Ajax call.
6. That promise is `yield`ed out, which comes back to the `*foo(2)`
   generator instance.
7. The `yield *` passes that promise back out to the `*foo(3)` generator
   instance. Another `yield *` passes the promise out to the `*bar()`
   generator instance. And yet again another `yield *` passes the promise
   out to the `run(..)` utility, which will wait on that promise (for the
   first Ajax request) to proceed.
8. When the promise resolves, its fulfillment message is sent to resume
   `*bar()`, which passes through the `yield *` into the `*foo(3)` instance, which then passes through the `yield *` to the `*foo(2)` generator
   instance, which then passes through the `yield *` to the normal `yield`
   that's waiting in the `*foo(3)` generator instance.
9. That first call's Ajax response is now immediately `return`ed from the
   `*foo(3)` generator instance, which sends that value back as the result of the `yield *` expression in the `*foo(2`) instance, and
   assigned to its local `val` variable.
10. Inside `*foo(2)`, a second Ajax request is made with `request(..)`,
     whose promise is `yield`ed back to the `*foo(1)` instance, and then
     `yield *` propagates all the way out to `run(..)` (step 7 again). When
     the promise resolves, the second Ajax response propagates all the
     way back into the `*foo(2)` generator instance, and is assigned to
     its local `val` variable.
11. Finally, the third Ajax request is made with `request(..)`, its
     promise goes out to `run(..)`, and then its resolution value comes
     all the way back, which is then `return`ed so that it comes back to
     the waiting `yield *` expression in `*bar()`.

Everything is clear until the 8th step.

> ...which then passes through the `yield *` to the normal `yield`
>       that's waiting in the `*foo(3)` generator instance.

Why waiting in `foo(3)`, not in `foo(2)`? I thought after Promise fulfillment, its value (`1`) is passed to `return yield request( "http://some.url/?v=" + val );` line, in place of `yield`, so we have `return 1` at the end of `foo(1)`. And then `1` is passed to `val = yield *foo( val - 1 );` line, again, in place of `yield`, so we have `val = 1` inside `foo(2)` call. After that, a second `request()` is made and `yield`s a Promise to `foo(3)`. 
Then `foo(3)` `yield`s the Promise to `bar()`, then `bar()` `yield`s the Promise to `run()`. `run()` waits on the second Promise, just as with the first promise, and so on.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxqahruk/)

What have I overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What have I overlooked?

Nothing. In steps 8 and 9, the generator they should be referring to is the one created by `foo(1)`, not by `foo(3)`.